# Connect ROSARIA to pionner robot using wifi

Tags: wireless, wifi, pioneer-3dx, p3dx, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a P3DX robot with an onboard pc running Windows.
I want to move it using a remote laptop running Linux with ROS and ROSARIA installed.

The problem is that ROSARIA uses Serial port to communicate with the robot, but in my case, I have to use a wireless connection between them. The solution proposed in the MobileRobot's doc is to use an external Serial-Wifi Bridge.  However, since the P3DX is already equiped with wifi, can I just use it to communicate with ROSARIA instead of using an external Serial-Wifi Bridge ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207338/connect-rosaria-to-pionner-robot-using-wifi/) by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2015-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-04-28**:
Yes you can. BTW the onboard computer should have Linux - Ubuntu OS to get the maximum out of ROSARIA package. Windows is not yet fully supported for ROS. You can however, check the ros for windows wiki where you have to build by source.

**Comment by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on 2015-04-29**:
When installing ROSARIA in my laptop it prompt me to install Libaria also. Since libaria use directly serial port or ethernet to communicate directly to the robot hardware, I think it's not necessary to install ROS in the robot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both the PC's (robot and remote pc) needs to have the same version of ROS running inorder for the robot to properly communicate. You should install Linux OS on your robot pc with ROS and ROSARIA to go further with you project. Also both pc's should have the same ros distro (Hydro or Indigo or Groovy).
Hope this helps.

Alex

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on 2015-05-14**:
it's working, thanks